# Undulator phase expression

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, accelerator-physics, synchrotron-radiation

About the technology of undulators (insertion device for synchrotron accelerators), [Walker1993](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-9002(93)90288-S) presented a formula for the phase of radiation emitted by the electrons passing through this device:

From the spectral angular distribution, $\frac{d^2I}{d\omega d\Omega}=\frac{e^2\omega^2}{16\pi^3\epsilon_0 c^3}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x'\exp{(i\delta)}dz\right|^2$, the phase $\delta$ is:
$$\delta=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\left(\frac{z}{2\gamma^2}+\frac{\int(x')^2dz}{2}\right)$$

I tried to prove this using the concise expression for spectrum of a moving charge, given by [Wang1993](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevE.47.4358), $\frac{d^2I}{d\omega dA}=\frac{e^2\omega^2}{16\pi^3\epsilon_0c}\left|\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\hat{n}(t')e^{i\omega t}dt\right|^2$, but i couldn't figure out how to properly parametrize the electron trajectory with respect to the observer time, then find $\hat{n}(t')$. I don't know if this is the correct path to demonstrate the expression.

Maybe you guys know something about the steps to prove this and can help me. I am a beginner at the subject of insertion devices physics, so i thank you all in advance for the help.

Moreover, i have other questions:

- The formula for the radiation pattern usually is expressed in terms of observer or emission time, $t$ or $t'$, respectively. How to pass from the time to $z$, the integral variable?
- [Walker2013](https://journals.aps.org/prab/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevSTAB.16.010704) presents another formula for phase, it is: $\phi(z)=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}(ct-z)=\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\left(\frac{l(z)}{\beta}-z\right)$. This is more clear to me, but how to pass from this formula to the previous one or the reverse?